# A criterion for a differential equation to be realized as an Euler-Lagrange equation on the infinite dimensional space

Tags: differential-equations, calculus-of-variations, infinite-dimensional-manifolds, geodesics

I study PDEs that arise in fluid dynamics in an infinite dimensional Riemannian geometric perspective. For example, Ebin-Marsden(1970) showed that the group of volume preserving diffeomorphisms has an infinite dimensional Banach manifold structure, and the solution of Euler equations for perfect fluid can be described as a geodesic equation. In this perspective, the Euler equations can be realized as a stationary point of the energy functional, i.e. an Euler-Lagrangian equation.

Now, there is another infinite dimensional space that I'm interested in studying, which is Met(M), the space of Riemannian metrics on M. Many people already worked on this space and it has an infinite dimensional manifold structure as well.

From the Exterior Differential System(EDS), we know that a given PDE is an Euler-Lagrange equation if and only if it satisfy the Helmholtz condition. This is a criterion on the finite dimenisonal setting. So my question is, is there is an infinite dimensional analogue of the Helmholtz condition to test whether a given PDE is an Euler-Lagrange equation or not? Thanks in advance!